# Show post content in the same page ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm creating a blog. in my index.js i have a left sidebar that shows the article links.
What I'm trying to do is when I click on the link the post content should be shown in the right sidebar of my index.js
At the moment it's been opened in a new page.

index.js

```
const IndexPage = ({ 
  data: {
    allMarkdownRemark: { edges },
  },
}) => {
  const PostData = edges[0]
  const Posts = edges
    .filter(edge => !!edge.node.frontmatter.date) // You can filter your posts based on some criteria
    .map(edge => <PostLink key={edge.node.id} post={edge.node} />)

  return (
    <div className='html-container'>
      <div className='main-container'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='left-sidebar'>
            <div className='logo'>
              <p>logo</p>
            </div>
            <div className='menu'>
              {Posts}

            </div>

            <div className='social'>
                <img src={twitch} />
                <img src={discord} />
                <img src={twitter} />
                <img src={email} />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className='right-sidebar'>
          
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

post-link.js

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const PostLink = ({ post }) => (
  <div>
    <Link to={"/blog"+post.frontmatter.slug}>
      {post.frontmatter.title}
      {/* {post.frontmatter.title} ({post.frontmatter.date}) */}
    </Link>
  </div>
)

export default PostLink
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the API of the `Link` and if it has an equivalent of [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) attribute.

Comment: Nothing like that. But: 'Sometimes you need to navigate to pages programmatically, such as during form submissions. In these cases, Link won’t work. By default, navigate operates the same way as a clicked Link component.'
That could work but I don't know how

Comment: I did it by pre-generating each page in order to navigate between them.